# Filter and move text in another column in substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
{'Phone': 'Fax(925) 482-1195', 'Fax': None},
{'Phone': 'Fax(406) 226-0317', 'Fax': None},
{'Phone': 'Fax+1 650-383-6305', 'Fax': None},
{'Phone': 'Phone(334) 585-1171', 'Fax': 'Fax(334) 585-1182'},
{'Phone': None, 'Fax': None},
{'Phone': 'Phone(334) 585-1171', 'Fax': 'Fax(334) 585-1176'}]
)
```

Which should look like:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is: for every row that I see "Fax", I want to truncate it and transfer this record to the column "Fax".

At first, I was trying to query only the matching with this filtering:

```
df[df['Phone'].str.contains("Fax") == True, "Fax"] = df[df['Phone'].str.contains("Fax") == True]
```

But it does not works, with the error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of rows, that is, a list of dicts.
Simplest approach would be to massage each row
prior to adding it to the dataframe.

```
rows = [ ... ]

def get_contacts(rows):
    for row in rows:
        phone, fax = row['Phone'], row['Fax']
        if 'Fax' in phone:
            phone, fax = None, phone
        yield phone, fax

df = pd.DataFrame(get_contacts(rows))
```

---

You can force `str` instead of `None` with a filter like this:

```
        ...
        yield clean(phone), clean(fax)
        ...

def clean(s, default=''):
    if s is None:
        return default
    return s
```

---

If you *really* prefer to stick to using Pandas,
you might want to

1. identify a mask of rows where `df.Phone` contains 'Fax', then
2. copy that subset into `df['Fax']`, then
3. blank out selected `df['Phone']` entries.

You can verify / debug each step by itself -- get (1) right
before moving on to attempt (2).

If you choose to go this route, [please post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your final solution.

Comment: Hey! Your code is working very fast. The only issue I'm having is for dealing with the None values... It returns TypeError

Comment: Your original dataset had a bunch of `None`s mixed in, so I thought that was how you preferred to represent missing numbers. Feel free to force them all to `str` if you find that more convenient. I added `def clean()` to show _one_ way of doing that.

Comment: Thanks, man. Solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option using .[assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



condition = df["Phone"].str.contains("fax", case=False)
df = df.assign(
    Fax=np.where(condition, df["Phone"], df["Fax"]),
    Phone=np.where(condition, "", df["Phone"])
).fillna("")

print(df)

                 Phone                 Fax
0                        Fax(925) 482-1195
1                        Fax(406) 226-0317
2                       Fax+1 650-383-6305
3  Phone(334) 585-1171   Fax(334) 585-1182
4                                         
5  Phone(334) 585-1171   Fax(334) 585-1176
```